# Is it possible to restore course backup from Moodle 2.x to Moodle 1.9(8)?

Tags: backup, restore, moodle

So that is the question. I need it because I create my course in Moodle 2.1 but there is Moodle 1.9 installed in my University. So I need the way to export/restore my course to older Moodle version. Thanx for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my knowledge, it's not possible to restore a 2.X backup to 1.9.